# Stuck on matrix exponential problem

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I want to show that the property $e^{tA}e^{tB}=e^{t(A+B)}$ implies that $AB=BA$. Here $A,B$ denotes matrices and $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Im stuck, have tried to expand both sides with their taylor series but not sure if this is the way to go.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: It follows from the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula (a bit of a sledgehammer).

Comment: You don't need BCH; just compute the coefficient of $t^2$ on both sides.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why is it enough to compute the coefficient of $t^{2}$ and how does one see that?

Comment: If you computed the coefficient of $t^2$ on both sides you would already know the answer to that question!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there an easy way to simplify the left hand side into only one sum, so that the coefficient of $t^{2}$ can easily be computed?

Comment: @Biggiez: the LHS is $\left( \sum A^k \frac{t^k}{k!} \right) \left( \sum B^k \frac{t^k}{k!} \right)$, and using standard facts about multiplying power series we get that the coefficient of $\frac{t^n}{n!}$ is $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} A^k B^{n-k}$, whereas on the RHS the coefficient is $(A + B)^n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Im having trouble with the simplification in the LHS leading to only one sum, could you write down the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate 2 times with respect to time $t$ the identity 
$$e^{tA}e^{tB}=e^{t(A+B)}$$
and then set $t=0$.

Comment: If I differentiate 2 times w.r.t to $t$ I obtain $(A+B)^{2}e^{tA}e^{tB}=(A+B)^{2}e^{t(A+B)}$. Just wondering if I have differentiated correctly?

Comment: in order to write the LHS, you assume A and B commutes.

Comment: @Biggiez: you have not differentiated correctly.

Comment: @Biggiez No, $\frac{d}{dt}[e^{tA}e^{tB}]=Ae^{tA}e^{tB}+e^{tA}e^{tB}B$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @CTNT Why does the matrix $B$ end up being multiplicated to the far right and not from the far left as in the first term in the sum?

Comment: Since B and $e^{tB}$ commutes $Be^{tB}=e^{tB}B$

Comment: @Biggiez $\frac{d}{dt}[e^{At}e^{Bt}]=\frac{d}{dt}[e^{At}]e^{Bt}+e^{At}\frac{d}{dt}[e^{Bt}]=Ae^{At}e^{Bt}+e^{At}Be^{Bt}=Ae^{At}e^{Bt}+e^{At}e^{Bt}B$ since $B$ and  $e^{Bt}$ commute.

Comment: If I've differentiated correctly this time: $L.H.S=(A^{2}+2BA+B^{2})e^{tA}e^{tB}=R.H.S=(A+B)^{2}e^{t(A+B)}$. Setting t=0 we obtain that $A^{2}+2BA+B^{2}=A^{2}+AB+BA+B^{2}$ which in turn gives us that $2BA=AB+BA$, so the property holds only if $BA=AB$ ?

Comment: @Biggiez Correct!

Answer (score -1):

**This is not what has been asked** but to show the identity is valid if $A$ and $B$ commutes, you can...

Define
$$
f(t) = e^{t(A+B)}e^{-tB}e^{-tA}
$$

Then,
$$
f'(t) = (A+B)e^{t(A+B)}e^{-tB}e^{-tA} - e^{t(A+B)}Be^{-tB}e^{-tA}
- e^{t(A+B)}e^{-tB}Ae^{-tA}
$$

if $A$ and $B$ commutes, we can factor out A and B from the last two.
$$
f'(t) = (A+B) f(t) - A f(t) - B f(t) = 0
$$

Therefore $f(t)$ is a constant, you can show that it's identity.

Comment: The question is about the converse: if $f(t)$ is a constant, show that $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: I may have understood your solution wrong. But aren't you now assuming that $A$ and $B$ commutes? The question was to show that the identity implies that $A,B$ commutes.

Comment: Yes, this shows if $AB=BA$, then the exponential identity holds.

Comment: @karakfa Yes I agree with your statement, the only problem is that the exercise is to show that that identity IMPLIES that $A$ and $B$ commutes. As Qiaochu already stated you have shown the converse of that.

Comment: Yes, right now you have both directions proved.